# Layout bug on question list page

Tags: bug

Is this the correct place for SO bug reports?

Just noticed this strange issue (notice the input box in the question preview):

[image]

It seems to be something to do with a URL immediately followed by a code block.

The question in question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789227/getting-a-child-inputs-ctrl-from-a-parent-directive

Comment: The entire page for [javascript] appears to be funky. I just looked and questions after [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789299/using-angular-1-3-ngmessage-for-form-submission-errors) were indented.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23 looks bizarre as well.  (...and now fixed)