# Possible XSS vulnerability on Stack Overflow?

Tags: bug, status-completed, security

So I was just browsing through the newest [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js) questions and I see the layout is all messed up.

[image]

The question you see has a snippet that starts with a `<form>` tag:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_ODW7OJfVhlRJEgFY0ppWzwEE"
    data-amount="2000"
    data-name="Demo Site"
    data-description="2 widgets ($20.00)"
    data-image="/128x128.png">
  </script>
</form>
```

Which seems to be rendering in the questions list.

[image]

Comment: You broke Meta.

Comment: Lots of pages are really screwy. Meta is now totally borked

Comment: Uh... Whups. :D

Comment: I mostly un-broke it by making the summary a little longer. But that illustrated the point *very nicely*! There is still a problem visible on the questions page but at least the rest of the page isn't b0rken now.

Comment: I've flagged the question on SO for a mod to look at.

Comment: For me (Chrome W7), meta is fine, but the [question lists](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Msmu1.jpg) are screwed up.

Comment: I guess it's related to this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276229/layout-bug-on-question-list-page

Comment: [related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276227/why-is-the-i-in-the-title-to-question-26789031-causing-the-formatting-of-the-o)

Comment: It seems to be any question with a code block that falls within the preview character limit

Comment: I'm too lazy to save my screenshot on imgur, but basically everything is broken. newest-in-tag pages specifically

Comment: Apparently this is quite common given the 5 or so duplicates that came in.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

A fix for this just rolled out.

I've been reworking how we render some common bits of pages, and messed up encoding rules on the body summary in the refactor.